# Matplotlib interactive bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to explore interactive feature in matplotlib, basically user picks a y value by clicking on the graph, depending on the value the user picked, a horizontal line is drawn. And according to that line the color of barchart should change (how far is the value from the mean).

My program draws the user picked value but the color of bars do not change according. The click event calls my compare value function which draws the line but do not change color.  My code is as follows, any help would be appreciated

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])
df=df.T
n = len(df)
std = df.std()
means = df.mean() 


ci = (1.96*std/(n**0.5))
cu = list(means + ci)
cl = list(means - ci)
yerror = list(zip(cl , cu))
lab =list(df.columns)
x = np.arange(len(lab))


my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0.,vmax=1.)


def cmp_val(n):
    data_c=list((n - means))
    data_c = [x / max(data_c) for x in data_c]
    for i in range(len(data_c)):
        if data_c[i] > 0:
            my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Blues')
            colors = my_cmap(norm(data_c[i]))
            bar[i].set_facecolor(colors)
        if data_c[i] < 0:
            my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Reds')
            colors = my_cmap(norm(data_c[i]*-1))
            bar[i].set_facecolor(colors)
    plt.axhline(y=n, xmin=0, xmax=1, c = 'lightslategray', linestyle = ':')

    return n


plt.figure()
bar=plt.bar(x ,list(means), width=x[1]-x[0], edgecolor='black',  yerr= ci,capsize= 20)
plt.xticks(x, lab)

def onclick(event):
    plt.cla()
    bar=plt.bar(x ,list(means), width=x[1]-x[0], edgecolor='black',  yerr= ci,capsize= 20)
    cmp_val(event.ydata)

    plt.gca().set_title('{}'.format(event.ydata))
    plt.xticks(x, lab)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it help if you add `plt.draw()` at the end of `onclick()`? See https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.draw.html and the linked examples there.

Comment: plt.draw() fixes one issue i did not mention, the line was drawn only when i select any of the figure buttons pan,zoom. Now using plt.draw() draws a line without selecting these buttons.

Comment: bar[i] is a (class 'matplotlib.patches.Rectangle') which goes undetected when using it in onclick function

Comment: `bar` is a local variable inside `onclick()`. You can change it to global by adding a line at the start of `onclick()`: `global bar`

Comment: yes but bar[i].set_facecolor('') in cmp_val function is a (class 'matplotlib.patches.Rectangle')

Comment: Your code seems to work as intended when `global bar` and `plt.draw()` are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood how you wanted to normalize your color coding, but I rewrote your code to make it work. Hopefully you'll be able to adapt the code to your needs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000, 200000, 3650),
                   np.random.normal(43000, 100000, 3650),
                   np.random.normal(43500, 140000, 3650),
                   np.random.normal(48000, 70000, 3650)],
                  index=[1992, 1993, 1994, 1995])
df = df.T
n = len(df)
std = df.std()
means = df.mean()

ci = (1.96 * std / (n ** 0.5))
cu = list(means + ci)
cl = list(means - ci)
yerror = list(zip(cl, cu))
lab = list(df.columns)
x = np.arange(len(lab))

my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm_r')
my_norm = mcolors.Normalize(vmin=-means.max(), vmax=means.max())


def color_bars(val, rectangles, cmap, norm):
    heights = np.array([b.get_height() for b in rectangles])
    diff = heights - val
    colors = cmap(norm(diff))
    for rectangle, color in zip(rectangles, colors):
        rectangle.set_facecolor(color)
    fig.canvas.draw()


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.bar(x, means, width=x[1] - x[0], edgecolor='black', yerr=ci, capsize=20)
hline = ax.axhline(y=0, c='lightslategray', linestyle=':')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(lab)


def onclick(event):
    if event.inaxes:
        ax.set_title('{:.2f}'.format(event.ydata))
        hline.set_ydata([event.ydata, event.ydata])
        color_bars(event.ydata, bars, cmap=my_cmap, norm=my_norm)
        fig.canvas.draw()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you this helps. I know my coloring bar implementation is shaky but now got to work. The idea is if user val is greater than bar height paint blue if user val is less than bar height paint red and coloring should follow gradient. You have it correct except choose color scheme coolwarm instead of colorwarm_r